# GMGridView with UIPageControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am doing a project and looking into using the GMGridView found here: https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView.

Has anyone used it and added a UIPageControl?  If so, how can it be done?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the following changes:-

```
  1.)In Demo1ViewController.h  do
    @interface Demo1ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        UIPageControl *pageCont;
    }
    @end

2.)In Demo1ViewController.m  do

In load view method write:-

      pageCont=[[UIPageControl alloc]init];
        pageCont.numberOfPages=10// set this according to your total pages
        pageCont.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        [pageCont addTarget:self action:@selector(pagechanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        pageCont.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30);// set frame as your requirements
        [self.view addSubview:pageCont]; 
        _gmGridView.delegate=self;

    and add these two methods

    -(IBAction)pagechanged:(id)sender
    {
// add code according  to your requirements if needed

    }

    - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        CGFloat pageWidth = _gmGridView.frame.size.width; 
        float fractionalPage = _gmGridView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
        NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
        pageCont.currentPage = page; 
    }
```

This works with horizontal layout of gmgrid view, you can change the logic of didscroll method for vertical scrolling if required.
It might helps you.
Happy coding!

Comment: Awesome, worked great!!!  In pageChanged I will need to advance to the page right?  I will look for a method to do that, unless you want to share!!  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Hello there, I'm just wondering: how can I figure out my "pageCont.numberOfPages=10// set this according to your total pages" since GMGridView fixes this dynamically? The contents of my gridview is not fixed and may increase or decrease. Can this pageCont.numberOfPages be assigned dynamically? Would you have any ideas on how? Thanks. Would greatly appreciate your help